# How to iterate via array in ruby and compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have for example such array:

```
40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55 etc
```

Via post-query i'm getting from select some value: for example 40-50, then i split this value for two numbers: `40 and 50` (but that's not the main problem, with split, question is in another).
I need to compare this two values, so that array values must be in `[40...50)` values. So all what is in this interval i must select for my other calculations...
How to do this? aybe with map, but how?

Comment: @sawa , cpilko, bažmegakapa, Mark, hayden  thank you admins! what is bad in this question? are you all blind, or maybe stupid at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
arr = [40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55]
min, max = "40-50".split('-').map {|s| s.to_i }
range = min..max
arr.select {|n| range.include? n }

=> [40, 42, 45, 49, 50]
```

This will include 50

use `range = 40...50` to exclude 50

thanks @gregates

#### See [it running equally on all versions](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-iterate-via-array-in-ruby-and-compare.rb&versions=%2a&run=true)

Comment: but also note, that 40 i must select, but 50 not

Comment: no need to do `to_a` on the range. Range#include? works fine.

Comment: the range `(40...50)` includes 40 but not 50 -- note the crucial third `.`

Comment: @gregates: oh, you did mention the third dot too. Didn't see that :)

Comment: thank you... also "thank's" to blind admins.... who close that question

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using rails, you can leverage its `.in?` helper to make your code a bit more readable

```
arr = [40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55]
arr.select{|a| a.in?(40..49)} # => [40, 42, 45, 49]
```

By the way, if you use three dots to construct a range, it doesn't include the upper boundary.

```
arr = [40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55]
puts arr.select{|a| a.in?(40...50)} # => [40, 42, 45, 49]
```

Ranges and dots

```
(1..5).to_a # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(1...5).to_a # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: standard library: (40...50).include?(a)

Comment: Yeah, it was in another answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
orig_arr=[40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55]
range_str='40-50'
min, max = range_str.split("-").map{|num| num.to_i}
orig_arr.select{|x| (min..max) === x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a string `'40-50`'

Then you will get numbers for your range

```
'40-50'.split('-').map(&:to_i) #=> [40,50]
```

One way is using intersection:

```
(40...50).to_a & [40,42,45,49,50,52,54,55] #=> [40,42,45,49]
```

Comment: "The fastest" in what terms, exactly?